# Automate "yes" to Popen SSH command

Tags: c++, c

Hi i am writing a C++ program to automate SSH connection to an AWS instance with the `popen` function.

```
void initiate_ssh(char ip[100]){

char ssh[250];
FILE* fp;
strcpy(ssh,"ssh -i theKey.pem ec2-user@");
strcat(ssh,ip);
fp=popen(ssh,"w");
if(fp){
 // respond yes automatically 
    }
pclose(fp);

}
```

I have searched through numerous threads but i can only find similar situations in python but i am not too familiar with python. So i need to automatically pipe "yes" to the `popen`  in order to get access remote access to the instance.

Comment: What do you need to respond to?

Comment: i need the program to automatically respond yes when the ssh connection is established

Comment: I would personally just use [expect](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) for something like that.

Comment: @phenom ok, but what is the question that it needs to answer to? Does it come from the `ssh` client itself or is the question asked through the established connection by the server?

Comment: As you are using `pipe` already, why not use yes? SO has a nice question(and answers) about it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102484/346700

Comment: automatically accepting the keys to the instance (server) @walnut

Comment: @phenom There is a reason that this question is asked. Note that ignoring it or disabling it as suggested in the answer means that you will be more vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39990/is-it-safe-to-disable-ssh-host-key-checking-if-key-based-authentication-is-used. You should ideally know the host key before establishing the first connection.

Answer (score 2):

Here we see an "XY problem". You want to automatically accept host keys (this is "X"). You think that you can do that by automatically typing "yes" at the prompt (this is "Y"). You are stuck on that, so you ask how to do Y. But there is an even easier way to do X.

[Here's how to do X](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh):

add the option `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to your SSH command.

```
strcpy(ssh,"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i theKey.pem ec2-user@");
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I assume the `ssh` buffer is already long enough to contain this extra option.

Comment: In recent OpenSSH versions there is another value for the option: `accept-new`, which will accept keys for new hosts, but not changed keys for already known hosts. That would be a more secure default and mimic answering "yes" more closely.